# Wordpress custom post type & custom taxonomy reset (performance issue)

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed a plugin that reads a csv file in order to create 4 different custom taxonomies (Categories) and 1 custom post type (Post) using PHP and WordPress.

On the Initial import the execution time is less than 6 seconds, however the second time execution takes more than 1 minute in order to reset and re-upload the data.
The issue that I found is on the resetAllPosts function (see code)

```
public function resetAllPosts() {
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'psp',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 100
) );

// remove all taxonomies will take too long..
// delete all custom taxonomies terms
$terms_payment  = get_terms( 'payment', array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
$terms_country  = get_terms( 'country', array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
$terms_currency = get_terms( 'currency', array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
$terms_provider = get_terms( 'provider', array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'hide_empty' => false ) );

foreach ( $terms_payment as $value ) {
    wp_delete_term( $value, 'payment' );
}
foreach ( $terms_country as $value ) {
    wp_delete_term( $value, 'country' );
}
foreach ( $terms_currency as $value ) {
    wp_delete_term( $value, 'currency' );
}
foreach ( $terms_provider as $value ) {
    wp_delete_term( $value, 'provider' );
}

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    // remove the relation between the post and the taxonomies
    //wp_delete_object_term_relationships(get_the_ID(),array("provider","payment","currency","country"));

    // Remove the feature image from Media gallery
    //$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    //wp_delete_attachment( $post_thumbnail_id, true );

    // delete the post
    wp_delete_post( $post_id, "true" );


}

echo "Reset of all data success..";
}
```

I would like to know the best/fastest way to delete all terms data.

Comment: Just a note for `get_terms` : "Since 4.5.0, taxonomies should be passed via the ‘taxonomy’ argument in the $args array" https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/